# Ошибка при переписывание кода в функции

Tags: c++, массивы

Попалась вот такая задача:

В двумерный массив вставить в конец столько строк, сколько четных чисел расположено в первой строке массива (новые строки заполнять этими четными числами). Затем из полученного массива удалить столько последних столбцов, сколько нечетных чисел стоит в первом столбце массива. Если число столбцов меньше, чем требуется, выдать ошибку, что нельзя обработать.

Моя реализация, которая работает:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <ctime> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int m = 100, n = 100;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int n1, n2; // n- столбцы, m -строки 
    cout  <<  "Введите размерность массива m х n: \n";
    cin  >> n1 >> n2;

    int y1;
    cout  <<  "Введите нижний предел для генерации случайных чисел: \n";
    cin  >>  y1;

    int y2;
    cout  <<  "Введите верхний предел для генерации случайных чисел: \n";
    cin  >>  y2;

    int x[m][n];

    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            x[i][j] = y1 + rand() % (y2 - y1 + 1);

    cout  <<  "Исходный массив: \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            cout  <<  x[i][j]  <<  "\t";
        cout  <<  "\n";
    }

    int* l;
    int* h;

    l = (int*)malloc(n1 * sizeof(int));
    h = (int*)malloc(n2 * sizeof(int));

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n1; i++)
        if (x[i][0] % 2 != 0) k++;

    int ch = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n2; i++)
        if (x[0][i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
                x[n1 + ch][j] = x[0][i];
            ch++;
        }

    if (k < n2)
    {
        n1 = n1 + ch - 1;
        n2 = n2 - k;
        l = (int*) realloc(l, (int)n1);
        h = (int*) realloc(h, (int)n2);

        cout  <<  "\nРезультирующий массив: \n";

        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
                cout  <<  x[i][j]  <<  "\t";
            cout  <<  "\n";
        }
    }
    else cout  <<  "\n Обработать невозможно \n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Пытался *переделать в функции*, но это не работает.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <ctime> 
using namespace std;
//Прототипы функций 

int** create_array(int n1, int n2, int y3, int y4);

void print_array(int n1, int n2, int** a);

//Нахождение количества нечетных чисел в 1 ст в динамическом массиве размера n 
int count_even_numbers(int* b, int n);

//Нахождение количества четных чисел в 1 стр в динамическом массиве размера n 
int count_even_numbers_in_array(int* b, int n);

//нахождение кол-ва нечёт 
int nechet(int n1, int** a);

//нахождение кол-ва чёт 
int chet(int n2, int** a);

//нахождение кол-ва чёт и создание строк 
void chet_mas(int n1, int n2, int** a);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int n1, n2; // n- столбцы, m -строки 
    cout << "Введите размерность массива m х n: \n";
    cin >> n1 >> n2;

    int y1;
    cout << "Введите нижний предел для генерации случайных чисел: \n";
    cin >> y1;

    int y2;
    cout << "Введите верхний предел для генерации случайных чисел: \n";
    cin >> y2;

    int** x;
    x = create_array(n1, n2, y1, y2);
    cout << "\n Исходный массив: \n";
    print_array(n1, n2, x);

    int* l;
    int* h;

    l = (int*)malloc(n1 * sizeof(int));
    h = (int*)malloc(n2 * sizeof(int));

    int k, ch;

    k = nechet(n1, x);
    ch = chet(n2, x);

    chet_mas(n1, n2, x);

    if (k < n2)
    {
        n1 = n1 + ch - 1;
        n2 = n2 - k;
        l = (int*)realloc(l, (int)n1);
        h = (int*)realloc(h, (int)n2);

        cout << "\n Результирующий массив: \n";
        print_array(n1, n2, x);
    }
    else cout << "\n Обработать невозможно \n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Реализация функций 

//Создание динамического массива размера n и заполнение его случайными числами вдиапазоне [a,b] 
int** create_array(int n1, int n2, int y3, int y4)
{
    int** a;
    a = new int* [n1];
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new int[n2];
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            a[i][j] = y3 + rand() % (y4 - y3 + 1);
    }
    return a;
}

//Вывод на экран динамического массива b размера n 
void print_array(int n1, int n2, int** a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//нахождение кол-ва нечёт 
int nechet(int n1, int** a)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        if (a[i][0] % 2 != 0) k++;
    return k;
}

//нахождение кол-ва чёт 
int chet(int n2, int** a)
{
    int ch = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n2; i++)
        if (a[0][i] % 2 == 0)
            ch++;
    return ch;
}

//нахождение кол-ва чёт и создание строк 
void chet_mas(int n1, int n2, int** a)
{
    int f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        if (a[0][i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
                a[n1 + f][j] = a[0][i];
            f++;
        }
}
```

И появляется следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что следует мне поправить? Благодарю за любую помощь.

Comment: Что такое `l` и `h` и что они делают в вашем коде? В обоих вариантах.

Comment: @AnT, они меняют размер массива, это указатели

Comment: ©Adam Cobain: Что значит "меняют размер массива"? Ещё раз у вас в коде массивы `l` и `h` никак не используются вообще. Они никому не нужны. Вопрос: зачем эти никому не нужные массивы болтаются у вас в коде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде содержится явный доступ за пределы массива. В первом варианте это

```
x[n1 + ch][j]
```

в `main`, а во втором варианте это

```
a[n1 + f][j]
```

в `chat_mas`. Кто вам разрешил обращаться по индексу `n1 + что-то`, когда массив имеет размер `[n1]`?

Ваш первый вариант в результате такого доступа не падает потому, что массив `x` объявлен с размером `[100][100]`, то есть "с запасом", если величина `n1` существенно меньше `100`. Но если величина `n1` приблизится к `100`, то вылетать за пределы массива и падать начнет и ваш первый вариант.

Во втором варианте вы создаете массив точного размера `[n1][n2]`. Этот вариант, разумеется, будет вылетать за пределы массива и падать всегда. Что вы и наблюдаете.

Comment: Спасибо за замечания.